# Get page by path - honoring permalink settings (urls w/slashes)

Tags: permalinks, urls

Let's say I have a `page` with the name `sample-page`.

I can do this:

```
get_page_by_path('sample-page')
```

To get that page.

---

Now, let's say I want to get a post where the URL to that post is `/post/8`.

If I do

```
get_page_by_path('post/8'); // with or without leading slash
```

I get back `null`.

How do I retrieve the page/post for any given URL in WP?

Edit: here's a screenshot that might add some clarity to my issue

[image]

Given the frontend permalink URL is `/post/33`, how do I take that string and do the opposite? How do I take `/post/33` and get the post from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `url_to_postid()` to get the post ID with the relative page url.

```
$url = '/page-parent/page/';
$post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/

Comment: This seems to return `0` for me. `url_to_postid('post/8')` returns `0`.

Comment: did you try with a front slash?

Comment: Yep it acts the same with or without a leading slash.

Comment: @JoshuaSoileau @MarkMarzeotti Function `url_to_postid()`  **will not work with relative URL**. One of the first things that the function checks is whether the URL belongs to the domain of the site.

Comment: Even giving a full URL doesn't seem to work:
`home_url('/post/33/')` returns `"https://my_site.com/post/33/"`, but `get_page_by_path( home_url('/post/33/') )` and `url_to_postid( home_url('/post/33/') )` both return `null`